# Why cannot import submudule, while can import module?

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, snappy

I have this line in a cloned GitHub project:

```
from snappy import jpy
```

I run in terminal:

```
pip3 install snappy
```

also:

```
pip3 install jpy
```

These run perfectly.

In a python shell, I run:

```
import snappy
```

I also run this:

```
from snappy import jpy
```

which gives this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'jpy'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `from snappy import jpy` <-- why do you think that should work?  I see zero mentions about [jpy] in the [project](https://github.com/andrix/python-snappy).

Comment: I am trying to implement this: https://github.com/ec-better/better-demo-0001/blob/master/src/main/app-resources/notebook/libexec/input.ipynb